# How to mock a imported function in vue component?

Tags: jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm testing my vue component, and I want to mock a function imported in component:

```js
    // backtop.vue

    <template>
      <transition name="ten-fade-in">
        <div
          v-if="_finishVisible"
          class="ten-backtop"
          :style="{
            right: _offsetRight,
            bottom: _offsetBottom
          }"
          @click="handleClick"
        >
          <!-- @slot 回到顶部内容 -->
          <slot>
            <ten-button
              class="ten-backtop-button"
              theme="default"
              icon="backtop"
              round
              icon-only
            />
          </slot>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </template>

    <script>
    import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
    import TenButton from '../button';
    import DomHelper from '@/components/scripts/utils/dom-helper';

    const { scrollTo, getScroll } = DomHelper;
```

And all I want is to mock the "scrollTo" function.

```js
    // backtop.test.js

    import Vue from "vue";
    import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
    jest.mock('@/components/scripts/utils/dom-helper', () => ({
      scrollTo: jest.fn()
    }));
    import DomHelper from '@/components/scripts/utils/dom-helper';
    const { scrollTo } = DomHelper;
    import Backtop from '../backtop.vue';
```

But when I run the test, jest still uses the original real module in `backtop.vue`, the mock module only worked in `backtop.test.js` but didn't work in `backtop.vue`, any solution please?

Comment: Try to use relative path instead of `'@/components/...`. I'm not sure what happens with `@` aliases in your case, they are possible not recognized as the same module. And for the record, you don't need to mock a module here. Since DomHelper is default export (which isn't too great because this disables tree shaking) you can mock DomHelper.scrollTo method with spyOn.

Comment: Tanks for your reply, I've used relative path but not worked, the mock only worked in `backtop.test.js` but didn't work in `backtop.vue`.